# Getting a CloudKit User's (Real) Email Address

Tags: cloudkit

I know I can look up a CloudKit user's unique ID like this:

```
CKContainer.default().fetchUserRecordID() { recordID, error in
  if let recordID = recordID{
    print(recordID.recordName) //_abcdef1234...
  }
}
```

And then I can ask them for permission to grant access to their contact info like this:

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(.userDiscoverability){ status, error in
  //...
}
```

And then I can look up their email address like this:

```
let userInfo = CKUserIdentityLookupInfo(userRecordID: recordID)
if let email = userInfo.emailAddress{
  print(email) // user@example.com
}
```

But what I'm not clear on, is **what is that email address**? Is that their *actual* **Apple ID email** that Apple stores in their iCloud account? Or is it just whatever they happen to put in the Contacts app on their Mac or iOS device?

I want to know how reliable that email is. If ownership of that email address is not verified through the above techniques, then I'll pursue a different way of getting the user's email address.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've tried this and emailAddress is always nil for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: No, I never did figure this out. I never tried it in a production CloudKit database, though. That might be why I never got consistent results for a user's data.